# High Disk Usage: New Laravel Project Consuming 2.09GB

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**What problem am I experiencing?**

- I'm encountering a persistent issue when creating a new Laravel project using the command 'composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app.'
- The vendor folder for the project has expanded to a substantial size of 2.09GB.
- Despite reinstalling Composer, the problem persists.
- Attempting to address the issue, I've deleted the vendor folder and rerun 'composer install,' but the process still takes an excessive amount of time and downloads an additional 2.09GB of data.

**What have I tried?**

- I have reinstalled Composer in an attempt to resolve the issue.
- I tried deleting the vendor folder and running 'composer install' again.
- Ideally, I expected these steps to mitigate the problem and result in a more reasonable vendor folder size during the creation of a new Laravel project. However, the issue persists, and the process remains time-consuming with a total download of 2.09GB.

Composer.json

```js
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: What do you have in your composer.json? What packages do you have required? If it's Linux or Mac, go inside your vendor file and run `du -sh *`. This will give you the size of every folder in it. That should help you pinpoint which package it is

Comment: I've shared the composer.json file for my Laravel project, which you can find here (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/composer.json). Additionally, I've observed that there is a folder inside my vendor called 'sebastian' with a size of 1.01GB. I hope this detail helps in pinpointing the source of the large vendor folder size. Your assistance is much appreciated. Let me know if you have any insights. Thank you!

Comment: How odd. My `sebastian` folder is only 828k. Can you check the contents of that folder?

Comment: it might be the composer. try to run "composer clear-cache" to see if any thing change.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. I've created a video to provide a closer look at the contents and sizes of the 'sebastian' folder inside my vendor directory. You can view it https://streamable.com/oa6sdp.
Despite running 'composer clear-cache,' unfortunately, the issue persists. I appreciate any further guidance or insights you may have. Thank you!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/laravel-53-project-size-is-very-big suggests it could be missing zip packages, but that's just a random guess. Your folders are still extremely large. For instance, my combined recursion-context/type/version folders are 172KB (Mac) vs your 167MB (windows).

Comment: You also have way too many files. For those 3 folders, you have 210 files, 76 folders. I have a total of 47 times. Compare your contents to the repositories at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann?tab=repositories . For each one, I just have a handful of files in the top level, and the full contents of the src directory

Comment: To provide more context, I created a Laravel project about a month ago, and at that time, the combined size of recursion-context/type/version folders was 140KB. However, with a new project created recently, I've noticed that this size has increased to 167MB.

Comment: I have attached an image showcasing the file differences in the 'vendor/sebastian/recursion-context' folder. In the newer project, additional folders such as '.github,' '.phive,' '.psalm,' and several others are present compared to my project from last month. This is contributing to a larger size in the newer project, whereas the size of the folder in last month's project is within the expected range.
Image : https://i2.paste.pics/f5e9f1fb7e22ee4c5f33fee02c22f917.png

Comment: I've included my composer.json file in the question.

Comment: `du -hs *` from that folder; see where it all is. Continue to drill down into the resulting directories.

Comment: After further investigation, I drilled down into the vendor folder and discovered that all the dependencies contain a hidden folder '.git,' which is unexpectedly large. It seems to be contributing significantly to the overall size issue. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to handle this or if there's a way to exclude these '.git' folders during the project creation process. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/43359 suggests running `composer clear-cache`, so try that between deleting the vendor folder and running the install again

Comment: Also check `composer config --list` and make sure that `preferred-install` is set to `dist`. I would think that the composer.json would override it, but it's good to check, just in case

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll follow your recommendations let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, now it worked! After running the commands 'composer clear-cache' and 'composer config preferred-install dist,' I encountered an error for each dependency, prompting me to enable the .zip extension in the php.ini file. Once I enabled it, everything worked perfectly fine. Thanks for your guidance!